# Relation not working properly using in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

I have a Post table that contains posts and media_images contains images related to a specific post. This is the relation that i'm using but in present scenario if post does not have image then no post is returned but i  want to return post also when there in no image.

```
  $where[] = ['category_id', '=', $request->category_id];
            return Posts::where($where)->with('media_images', 'category')->WhereHas('media_images', function ($query) use ($media_id) {
                if (!empty($media_id)) {
                    $query->InMediaId($media_id);
                } 
            })->paginate(10);
```

Comment: whereHas('media_images') will show only posts with media_images. But if you want all posts, consider using leftJoin('media_images') instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can add [orHas](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.html#method_orHas) to your query ,it Add a relationship count / exists condition to the query

```
 $where[] = ['category_id', '=', $request->category_id];
            return Posts::where($where)->with('media_images', 'category')->WhereHas('media_images', function ($query) use ($media_id) {
                if (!empty($media_id)) {
                    $query->InMediaId($media_id);
                } 
            })->orHas('media_images','=',0)->paginate(10);
```

Comment: nice solution, I like this.

Comment: @OMR : Thanks, this query is working but it is returning other categories data also category_id is in post table, when i remove orHas it returns data category wise but then it does not show data which do not have images, can you please  tell me what's the issue